# How do you use a default protocol implementation with performSelector in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, protocols, default, implementation

I created a protocol with a single method and a default implementation by creating an extension to that protocol.  My app crashes because perform selector doesn't recognize the default implementation.

The method can actually be called directly with no problems.  Using respondsToSelector for the method returns false, and performSelector for the method crashes.

Implementing the protocol in the actual class, or in an extension of the class makes it work, but that defeats the purpose of the default implementation.

I also filed a bug report to apple.

```
public protocol TestProtocol
{
  func testMethod()
}

extension TestProtocol
{
  public func testMethod() {
    print("testing the method...")
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, TestProtocol {

  @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.button.addTarget(self, action: "testMethod", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    print(self.respondsToSelector("testMethod"))
    self.testMethod()
//    self.performSelector("testMethod")
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a bug regardless, but try adding @objc to the protocol and extension method. This might just not work though, protocol extensions don't make sense in Objc.

Comment: Nope, extensions can't use "@objc".  And putting "@objc" in the protocol method makes it so that the default implementation isn't actually going to be used.  Pretty much this forces me to implement it in the class. So there is no way to call a default implementation of a protocol method using a selector because protocol extensions don't work with objective-c...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. There's no reason protocol extensions couldn't *sort of* work in Objective-C by having all classes implement them "separately", but I doubt that the Swift team will implement that.

Answer (score 2):

Work around is to just define some other method and have that call the default method.